# How should I implement cache in my web applications (Java), in a WebLogic environment

Tags: java, caching, web-applications, weblogic, ehcache

I'm creating a web application in Java, in a WebLogic application server.

How can I implement cache? Is there a recommended library? Does WebLogic offer any special support for this? Should I use a generic library such as [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/)?

Comment: Are you thinking of database cache? Like 2º level hibernate cache? If this is the case ehcache is recommended.

Comment: @edubriguenti: I hadn't thought about it, but I guess both 1st and 2nd level cache. EhCache can be used for 2nd level, as well?

Comment: 1st level cache is turned on by default when using hibernate. But second level cache needs to be configured with a cache library, like EhCache. But you need to have in mind some policies, like cache expiration, how many objects will live in the cache, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing in mind when you want to use cache is:

- Which part of your application needs improvement?

Normally, time consuming events are queries and others database interactions.

If there's something in your database that does not change much and you are searching for it a lot of times, it would be nice to cache it, since the object will be in memory to be retrieve, and no network request needs to be made.

Here is a cache policy configuration that you will need to think about in your application:

```
<defaultCache
maxElementsInMemory="1000"
eternal="false"
timeToIdleSeconds="120"
timeToLiveSeconds="120"
overflowToDisk="true"
/>

<cache name="Employee"
maxElementsInMemory="500"
eternal="true"
timeToIdleSeconds="0"
timeToLiveSeconds="0"
overflowToDisk="false"
/>
```

More information here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html) is an in-memory data grid solution that can provide 2nd level caching for Hibernate or other JPA-based frameworks such as TopLink.  Some of the Weblogic binary downloads include Coherence already bundled and can easily be configured to support applications running on Weblogic.  There are examples available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHIG/index.html).

One of the newer features provided is a the ability to update the cache based on changes in the database using Oracle GoldenGate.  This [HotCache](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHIG/golden_g.htm#COHIG4805) capability helps address issues with potentially stale data in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

If your JPA implementation is based on Toplink, then it's better to go with Oracle Coherence. If JPA implementation is based on Hibernate, infinispan is the right choice. For simple caching you can use ehcache. Distributed caching is better in infinispan compared to ehcache as it can be run as an individual process (infinispan Hot Rod Server) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some distrubuted caching mechanism that can support a clustered setup
JBoss cache is an option
https://community.jboss.org/thread/83152?start=0&tstart=0